# iOS 5: Pushing a view from a button

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I am trying to push a view from a button's IBAction and I am getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebView initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68902b0'
```

Code:

```
-(IBAction)showWebsite:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Web View!!!");
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"web"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

}
Any idea what could have gone wrong?
_(IBAction) is connected to `TouchUpInside`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .h of the second view is imported into the .m of the first view.

If you are using storyboard and just want to switch from one view to another view via a button you can place a button on the first view drop a second uiview controller onto storyboard then right click on the button and drag the connection to the second view.

To go back to the first view, repeat the process only this time connect the button on the second page to the first view.